# Como tratar uma string vazia?

Tags: java, string

Preciso converter uma string que pego de um arquivo texto e preencher uma classe pessoa onde, cada atributo da classe está separada por "," no arquivo texto. Os atributos são, somente: altura, peso, idade. No arquivo texto eles estão da seguinte forma:

```
1.50,58,20

1.60,60,15
```

e por ai vai...
O problema é que alguns desses atributos não são preenchidos e estou tendo problemas quando o ultimo atributo não é preenchido.

```
Ex:1.50,58,20

   1.60,60,

   1.70.80.30
```

Na linha 2 o ultimo não foi preenchido e preciso tratar isso. Meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
for(String s : result){
            String pessoa[];
            pessoa = s.split(",");
            System.out.println(pessoa[2]);
```

O `result` guarda, em cada posição, uma linha do arquivo e eu uso a variável `String pessoa[]` para guardar as partes separadas por "," o problema é que quando for `pessoa[2]` dá o erro `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2` pois como a ultima posição não estava preenchida, não há realmente o índice.

Como tratar esse erro? Ja tentei criar a variável e inicializar os índices como `null` ou `"" (vazio)` mas não deu certo.

Comment: Verifique o tamanho do array antes de usar `pessoa[2]`

Comment: Delimite a quantidade de Strings a serem retornadas no método split para 3, assim: s.split(",", 3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode resolver seu problema da seguinte forma abaixo, simplemente adicionando um parâmetro delimitando a quantidade máxima de resultados do método `split`, assim `s.split(",", 3)`.

```
for(String s : result){

    String pessoa[];
    pessoa = s.split(",", 3);
    System.out.println(pessoa[2]);

}
```

Dessa forma acima, quando se tentar acessar o índide de número 2 do array pessoa, será retornado uma string vazia e não um erro como ocorre no seu código.

Exemplo: [exemplo de utilização.](https://ideone.com/rLZEaN)

Comment: Yure, achei engraçado que isso tenha funcionado. Para mim o segundo parâmetro representa o número máximo de elementos no *array* resultante, mas não deveria mexer na lógica de *parsing*. Na verdade, `split(",")`  de acordo com os javadocs deve ser igual a `split(",", 0)`  (que também falha para essa entrada). Não percebi a diferença sútil que faz com que `split(",", 3)` ou `split(",", 5)` retornem arrays de 3 elementos nesse caso.

Comment: Sim, o segundo pârametro representa o número máximo de elementos a serem retornados, pórem no exemplo que utilizei a string tem 2 vírgulas, assim formando três elementos, onde o último é uma string vazia. Se a segunda vírgula for removida o erro será retornado novamente.

Comment: Pois é, o que não entra na minha cabeça é o porquê do `split(x, 0)` estar se comportando diferente de `split(x, n)` em relação ao último elemento vazio. Ao meu ver isso é, no mínimo, um problema com o Javadoc que não documenta esse comportamento.

Comment: Deu certo galera, muito obrigado. Nem imaginei que iria dar certo dessa forma com split, na minha cabeça também pensava que era só o numero máximo de elementos.

Answer (score 2):

Se você não tem como saber se o índice realmente existe, cheque o tamanho do array antes de acessá-lo. Por isso usamos laços de repetição, pois eles controlam o fluxo de forma a não deixar que tentemos acessar uma posição inexistente.

Você pode checar antes de exibir se aquele vetor é de tamanho 3 ou maior:

```
for(String s : result){
    String pessoa[];
    pessoa = s.split(",");
    System.out.println(pessoa.length >= 3 ? pessoa[2] : "");
}
```

Onde eu coloquei `""` você pode alterar para que quer que seja exibido caso o índice 2 não exista.

Veja em funcionamento no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/ap3JjU)